# How to add multiple product to cart by on click in shopify

Tags: api, shopify

I want to add multiple products to cart in a single click in Shopify.
 to apply the algorithm of frequently bought together products.

- Please help if anyone know about the Shopify API or related to above.
- Please guide with your knowledge.

Comment: I have built this function in my Shopify store. https://2018hismile.myshopify.com/pages/product-subscriptions Is this the functionality you are after?

Answer (score 1):

There is plenty of documentation online for that.

https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/getting-started/using-ajax-api